# Return only first of the month from column webi business objects

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a column as below, what can I do to only return only the rows that are the beginning of the month when the query is called. In the case of the image shown it would return 01/04/2017. I dont have the option to convert the date column to the 1st of the month or simply filter, as this column is a lot longer than shown, I would have to go through all the dates which isn't feasible.

Any ideas?

[image: Date column]

Thanks

Comment: Is the date always at the beginning? If so, pick off the first 10 characters or all characters until the first space and then convert that to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that returns a 1 if DayNumberOfMonth([Close Date]) = 1 or 0 if it doesn't. Filter on that variable and select 1